# Replacing the values in a column of a dataframe if it matches any character within another dataframe (with only one column)

Tags: r

I have a dataset including the case number, breed, and some other variables (not important for this question). I also have a separate list of 234 breeds that I wish to consider as "other purebreed" and i currently have read this list in as a separate dataframe called "other purebreds". I want to go through the breeds in my first dataset and where there are breeds that are also included in the "otherpurebreds" set, rename all of these as "other purebreed".

---

These are some things I have tried (all separate attempts).

```
testset$Breed[testset$Breed == (OtherPurebreds 1:234)] <- "Other Purebred"

testset[testset$Breed %in% OtherPurebreds]

testset %>% filter(Breed %in% OtherPurebreds)

testset$Breed[OtherPurebreds %in% testset$Breed] <- "Other Purebred"

library(data.table)
setDT(testset$Breed)[setDT(OtherPurebreds), on = "Breed", Breed := ifelse(is.na(Other Purebred), Breed, Other Purebred)]
```

Going back through my dataset i can see that after all of these different things, none of the breeds i expect to now say "Other purebreed" have changed.

---

Example data:

```
Data1 = data.frame(ID = c('1','2','3','4','5'), breed =c('spaniel','labrador','afghanhound','malinois','bulldog'))                  

Data2= data.frame(otherpurebreds = c('afghanhound', 'malinois'))
```

I want to go through the `data1` and pull out all cases matching any of the terms in the data2, and call these "other purebreds". i.e., i want all of the afghan hounds and malinois' in `data1` to now be called "other purebreed"

---

Please make any suggestions, thank you

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your data.

Comment: Try `ifelse(testset$Breed %in% OtherPurebreds, “Other Purebreds”, testset$Breed)` - if that doesnt work, folks can provide better assistance with a reproducible example

Comment: Thank you to the responders so far, please bear with me as I'm very new to R. I have added a reproducible example which I hope makes sense

Comment: @jpsmith thank you for your response. It came up with an error saying: Error: unexpected input in "ifelse(testset$Breed %in% OtherPurebreds, “"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with an `ifelse` statement in base R:

```
Data1$newbreed_base <- ifelse(Data1$breed %in% Data2$otherpurebreds, 
                              "Other Purebreeds", 
                              Data1$breed)
```

Output:

```
  ID       breed    newbreed_base
1  1     spaniel          spaniel
2  2    labrador         labrador
3  3 afghanhound Other Purebreeds
4  4    malinois Other Purebreeds
5  5     bulldog          bulldog
```

The `Data1$newbreed_base` creates a new column in the data frame, but  you can write over the `breed` column if you prefer (ie, `Data1$breed <- ifelse(...)`). I just created a new column for demonstration purposes.

Or in dplyr using `mutate` and `case_when`:

```
Data1 %>% 
  mutate(newbreed_dplyr = case_when(
    breed %in% Data2$otherpurebreds ~ "Other Purebreed",
    TRUE ~ breed
  ))
```

dplyr output:

```
  ID       breed  newbreed_dplyr
1  1     spaniel         spaniel
2  2    labrador        labrador
3  3 afghanhound Other Purebreed
4  4    malinois Other Purebreed
5  5     bulldog         bulldog
```

(Similarly, you can write over `breed` instead of create a new column with `mutate(breed = case_when(...)`)

Comment: thank you SO much, its worked! Apologies but how would i write over the breed column? Thank you again